Can't set time zone on M1 & 64 bit mac using command system setup
This is script which sets the timezones for various regions, so using the GUI is not an option, the script is for testing so not location based so I can't set the timezone based on the region.
The Failure
sudo systemsetup -settimeZone Europe/Paris
2024-10-28 01:02:12.591 systemsetup[693:6346] ### Error:-99 File:/AppleInternal/Library/BuildRoots/ce725a5f-c761-11ee-a4ec-b6ef2fd8d87b/Library/Caches/com.apple.xbs/Sources/Admin/InternetServices.m Line:379
Set TimeZone: Europe/Paris

I tried disabling csrutil thinking that was blocking the command from running, but it didn't.
csrutil status
System Integrity Protection status: disabled.

What is blocking the running of the command:
sudo systemsetup -settimeZone <timeZone>
There are many more timezones to be tested as part of a wider project at work.
Remember using the GUI is too inefficient, it has to be commands.

I just tested this in macOS 15.0.1. I get the same error message (a bug), but the command actually does work and exits with status 0 (success). Your output shows the same thing. To suppress the spurious error message, append 2>&- to the command.

hmm I might not have noticed the time change  for Paris, as it's nearly the same as UK time could you please try with: America/New_York I didn't get the time change for that.

damn you are right I just didn't notice it thank you, I re-enabled csrutil and still works.
